# TypeScript support in Vuera?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js

I have a React (with TypeScript) project and I want to integrate and embed Vue with TypeScript components in this React with TypeScript app.

I searched in the net and fount this links about this:

https://github.com/akxcv/vuera

https://medium.com/@aliafsah1988/how-to-usevue-js-inside-react-js-code-base-properly-3380f09b60f7

https://github.com/aliafsahnoudeh/vue-in-react-directly

https://github.com/aliafsahnoudeh/vue-in-react-web-component

I think Vuera is more suitable than others. but I need TypeScript support in Vuera. How can I achive that?

Is there any better way to integrate Vue and React (developed by TypeScript)?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I don't think you should go with Vuera. Last release was several years ago and it's looking for a maintainer. It will probably not support Vue 3 (typescript) anyway.

Comment: Well, what is solution